# Сортировка даты XMLGregorianCalendar в Stream

Tags: java, сортировка, дата, java-stream

Есть код:

```
    Collection<Project> projects = projectsRep.stream()
            .filter(t -> t.getDateFinish() != null)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Project::getDateFinish))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    printTasks(projects);
```

Метод getDateFinish() возвращает дату в формате XMLGregorianCalendar и отказывается сортировать.
Как отсортировать эту коллекцию по дате? При типе даты Date() все хорошо сортирует.
Ругается здесь: Project::getDateFinish

Comment: с сервера приходит именно такой формат: XMLGregorianCalendar

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае вам нужен компаратор. Выглядит он как отдельный класс:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class DateComparator implements Comparator<XMLGregorianCalendar>{
    @Override
    public int compare(XMLGregorianCalendar date1, XMLGregorianCalendar date2) {
        return date1.compare(date2);
    }
}
```

А теперь добавим его в наш стрим:

```
Collection<Project> projects = projectsRep.stream()
        .filter(t -> t.getDateFinish() != null)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Project::getDateFinish, new DateComparator()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Либо боле короткий вариант:

```
Collection<Project> projects = projectsRep.stream()
        .filter(t -> t.getDateFinish() != null)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Project::getDateFinish, XMLGregorianCalendar::compare).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: В коротком варианте, можно ли сделать так, чтобы в обратном порядке начилась сортировка?

Comment: @Ivan разумеется, можно. достаточно вызвать у компаратора метод reversed(). ответ изменил